# VB script in MS word doc to check all the cells inside all the tables to colours it

Tags: vba, ms-word

the doc have many table and each table has some text and other has numbers
I need the script to check if the cell has

- 1 shade it Green
- 2 = light green
- 3 = yellow and
- if 4 then red

I have tried this code but something went wrong

```vb
Sub CheckTableCellContent()
    Dim tbl As table
    Dim row As row
    Dim cell As cell
    
    For Each tbl In ActiveDocument.Tables
        For Each row In tbl.Rows
            For Each cell In row.Cells
                If IsNumeric(cell.Range.Text) And cell.Range.Text = "1" And cell.shading.BackgroundPatternColorIndex <> wdBrightGreen Then
                    cell.shading.BackgroundPatternColorIndex = wdBrightGreen
                ElseIf IsNumeric(cell.Range.Text) And cell.Range.Text = "2" And cell.shading.BackgroundPatternColorIndex <> wdLightGreen Then
                    cell.shading.BackgroundPatternColorIndex = wdLightGreen
                End If
            Next cell
        Next row
    Next tbl
    
End Sub
```

Comment: What went wrong? Is it a syntax error, are you getting an exception at runtime or is it simply not behaving as expected? Please, explain the problem in detail.

Comment: If cell.Range.Text Like "*1*" Then
                    cell.shading.BackgroundPatternColor = RGB(0, 176, 80)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check for an exact value don't use `Like` but compare the string directly. E.g., with `cell.Range.Text = "1"`.

But I suggest using the [Select Case statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/select-case-statement) for simplicity here:

```vb
Sub CheckTableCellContent()
    Dim tbl As table
    Dim row As row
    Dim cell As cell
    
    For Each tbl In ActiveDocument.Tables
        For Each row In tbl.Rows
            For Each cell In row.Cells
                Select Case cell.Range.Text
                    Case "1"
                        cell.shading.BackgroundPatternColor = RGB(0, 176, 80)
                    Case "2"
                        cell.shading.BackgroundPatternColor = RGB(146, 208, 80)
                    Case "3"
                        cell.shading.BackgroundPatternColor = RGB(255, 255, 0)
                    Case "4"
                        cell.shading.BackgroundPatternColor = RGB(255, 0, 0)
                    Case Else ' Reset to default color
                        cell.shading.BackgroundPatternColor = RGB(255, 255, 255)
                End Select
            Next cell
        Next row
    Next tbl
End Sub
```

If the value can change, also add an `Else` case to reset the color to white.